# How insert sql query code into database using php pdo

Tags: php

I have try to insert sql query to databse using php pdo in textarea but i get error network "post connection reset" and I find the error it's because the query code. Any one can help me how to use pdo insert can insert sql query?

this my query to insert:

```
$id = $_POST['id'];
$art = $_POST['txtart'];

$spq="INSERT INTO tb_post (id,articel) VALUES(:id,:art)";


$qpq = $db->prepare($spq);

$qpq->execute(array(':id'=>$id,

                  ':art'=>$art));
```

if i just insert text, the query can insert but if in text i write query code like `INSERT INTO / DELETE FROM / SELECT * FROM` or ...etc give error.

Comment: you need to show your code!

Comment: @Cyclone I already display above

Comment: You should use `bindParam()` before calling `execute()`, read the pdo [pdo manual](http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php)

Comment: @Cyclone But you can pass array to execute. http://php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.execute.php - second example

Comment: @Justinas - Still this question is too vague, he will need to show the code that doesn't work. I have no idea what he mean by `but if in text i write query code like "INSERT INTO / DELETE FROM / SELECT * FROM`

Comment: A simple way to track down the problem could also be to enable `error_reporting()` if not already done. Perhaps this is only a matter of syntax error in the sql query.

Comment: @Justinas still does not work, I saw her in the inspect element insert files I use are not called / fail and in the console displays the error "POST http://example.com/fungsi/f_u_post.php net :: ERR_CONNECTION_RESET"

Comment: @Cyclone pdo query that I use work well if I write an article without a code, as simple example as a sentence at the top and I ask my questions with complete pdo contains code but I can not make as above.

Comment: @Cyclone error_reporting() not give a result.

Comment: @RiskiFebriansyah - Put this at the top of your script `ini_set('display_errors', true); error_reporting(E_ALL);`

Comment: @Cyclone thanks but no result, just "failed to load respon data"..

Comment: @RiskiFebriansyah - Your question does not include enough information. We must see the entire code not just what you already added to your question.

Comment: @Cyclone i've open new thread in here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31310135/insert-pdo-cant-save-articel-record-if-any-mysql-query-code-in-articel with enough information.. :)

Answer (score 0):

All I can suggest is that some stupid SQL injection protection software gets scared by some SQL commands in the request.